# Definition of formal Laurent series vs Laurent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, terminology

From what I have read the definition of a formal Laurent series on $X$ is a series of the from:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(\lambda-\lambda_0)^n$$
where $a_n \in X \; \forall n$ (Abramovich and Aliprantis, 2002; pg49). How does this differ from the definition of a Laurent series (note no *formal*)?

Answer (score 1):

In general a "formal" series means we do not concern ourselves with matters of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

We say that $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k(z-z_0)^k$ is a *formal* Laurent series, if we want to stress the fact that, *it might not converge*.

Such *formal* series (power series, Laurent series, Neumann series, Fourier series, etc) are usually produced by some recursive process. For example, if one want to express the reciprocal of a given new Taylor series, as a power series, this produces a certain recursive formula for the coefficients of the new series. (Similarly, when we solve differential equations with the power series method, or expressing the solutions as Fourier series.) When we define recursively these coefficients, we do not know, in general, whether the newly defined series converges, and hence we call it *formal*.

Note that, it is possible for a Laurent series also not to converge anywhere but at $z=z_0$.